# Ruby's alias_method is method, but what about alias?

Tags: ruby, types, alias

I know that Ruby's `alias_method` is method, but what about `alias`?

I checked on [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.com) and when I search the `alias_method`, there are results like `Class: Module (Ruby 2.x.x)`, but in `alias`, there is no result like `Class: Module (Ruby 2.x.x)`.

I know the differences between them, in usage-level. I just want to know whether`alias` is method or not

Answer (score 1):

`alias` is a [keyword in ruby](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/keywords_rdoc.html), not a method.

Comment: It's trivial to see that it cannot possibly be a method, since it takes *unevaluated* expressions as arguments. Plus, even more obvious, it takes its arguments without commas separating them. The first one is already impossible in Ruby but the latter is really obvious: a method simply cannot change Ruby's syntax.